# How to find a possible set that sum to a given value

Tags: java, data-structures

Given an arraylist and a value, find if there is a triplet in array whose sum is equal to the given value. Found a solution using set

I just want to know what can be the logic what if we don't want to find triplet rather any possible number singlet, doublet, triplet, quartet,pentet, sixtet, septet. in this case `b` denotes that

```
        long n = 12;
        long k = 8;
        int b = 3;

        List<Long> sticksOrder = new ArrayList<>();
        for (long l = 1; l <= k; l++){
            sticksOrder.add(l);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < sticksOrder.size() - 2; i++) {
            Set<Long> s = new HashSet<>();
            long curr_sum = n - sticksOrder.get(i);
            for (int j = i + 1; j < sticksOrder.size(); j++)
            {
                if (s.contains(curr_sum - sticksOrder.get(j)))
                {
                    System.out.printf("Triplet is %d, %d, %d", sticksOrder.get(i), sticksOrder.get(j), curr_sum - sticksOrder.get(j));
                }
                s.add(sticksOrder.get(j));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is better known as the [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem).

it is 'NP-complete'. Meaning, if you have an efficient algorithm for me, then two things are going to happen:

[1] There are a whole boatload of algorithms, such as Travelling Salesman, which I can write as: "Transform the input so that it becomes a knapsack problem, use Beginner's amazing efficient Knapsack Problem Solver which can solve my problem quickly now that I have transformed the input so it looks like a knapsack problem, then transform the answer I get back into the answer of the Travelling Salesman problem I had; the transformations can also be efficient, making that whole pipeline efficient". In other words, solve one NP-complete problem and solve them all; that's what the *complete* part of `NP-complete` means (it encompasses all of the NP domain).

[2] You'll earn a few billion dollars as a consequence.

In other words, there is no proof that there is *no* efficient algorithm, but people have been looking **really really hard** for one and so far nobody's found one. So, for all relevant intents and purposes to a beginning programmer, assume that NP-complete problems cannot be calculated efficiently.

This is also somewhat freeing for you: **There is no gotcha trick** - just write it, really. Yes, it will be inefficient.

It also means that if you think you have an efficient way to do it, or if you think you can take an efficient algorithm and with a few tweaks you think you can turn it into one that retains its efficiency and can solve Knapsack, then either [A] billion dollars, yay, or [B] nope.

It's probably [B].

This algorithm you pasted is efficient. Therefore, it cannot be easily tweaked to do what you wanted it to - the tweak either is so non-obvious that the many, **many** people who looked didn't figure it out, or, will transform the algorithm into something quite different (as it'd have to be a not very efficient one).

A very roundabout way to get the conclusion: No, there is no way to tweak this algorithm.

It' hard to prove a negative, which is why I took a waltz through some fundamental informatics.

Answer (score 0):

The [SubSet sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) is a very hard problem.

Anyway we can find the optimal solution admiting `O(2^n)` cost.

Given a list of integers we can check if solution exists:

```
// check if, with these numbers, subset exists
private static boolean subSetSumExists(int [] xs, int index, int s) {

    // 0 reached
    if (s == 0)
        return true;

    // if is not 0 and we can't add or subtract, subset not exists
    if (index >= xs.length)
        return false;

    // here we use or not the index-th number
    return subSetSumExists(xs, index + 1, s) || subSetSumExists(xs, index + 1, s - xs[index]);

}
```

then, if we remove an integer and there is not solution, that integer is required, repeating that check and removing "irrelevant" integers we can get one **of multiple** solutions

```
// find one of multiple possible solutions (if any)
private static Optional<List<Integer>> subSetSum(List<Integer> xs, int s) {

    // while can remove elements, remove
    List<Integer> removed = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i = 0; i < xs.size(); i++) {
        int I = i;
        if(subSetSumExists(IntStream
                .range(0, xs.size())
                .filter(j -> j != I && !removed.contains(j))
                .map(xs::get)
                .toArray(), 0, s))
            removed.add(i);
    }

    // candidate list
    return Optional.of(IntStream
            .range(0, xs.size())
            .filter(j -> !removed.contains(j))
            .mapToObj(xs::get)
            .collect(toList()))
            // must check
            .filter(solution -> subSetSumExists(solution.stream().mapToInt(x -> x).toArray(), 0, s));
}
```

for example we can generate random instances

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // generate a random integer list
    List<Integer> xs = IntStream.range(0, 10).map(x -> ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(-10, 10)).boxed().collect(toList());

    // sum only 3 up to 6 of them
    List<Integer> indexShuffle = IntStream.range(0, 10).boxed().collect(toList());
    shuffle(indexShuffle);
    int s = indexShuffle.stream().limit(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(3, 7)).mapToInt(xs::get).sum();

    // the resulting list must sum `s` (but may be other list than the shuffled one)
    List<Integer> rs = subSetSum(xs, s).get();

    System.out.printf("Source: %s%nSeed: %d, Sum: %d, List: %s%n", xs, s, rs.stream().mapToInt(x -> x).sum(), rs);

}
```

with outputs

```
Source: [-9, -5, 4, -10, 4, 2, -2, -2, 2, 0]
Seed: -11, Sum: -11, List: [-5, -10, 2, 2]
...
Source: [9, -1, 1, 6, -6, 4, 6, 3, 0, -1]
Seed: 6, Sum: 6, List: [6]
...
Source: [-7, 3, 8, 2, 0, -3, 6, 3, -2, -1]
Seed: 7, Sum: 7, List: [6, 3, -2]
...
```